# V93k test method parameter names with forbidden Ruby characters

Tags: origen-sdk

The custom V93K test methods we use have parameter names that have characters that are forbidden in Ruby.  For example:

```
testmethodparameters

tm_1:
  "ComponentRule.ComponentRuleNameVariable" = "ComponentRuleMinConfig";
  "ComponentRule.ExecuteRules" = "true";
  "ComponentRule.RuleGroupNameVariable" = "ComponentRuleGroupName";
  "ComponentRule.ScriptNameVariable" = "ComponentRuleScriptName";
  "Softset.NumberOfPatternInfo" = "1";
  "Softset.PatternInfo0.EdgesPerVector" = "2";
```

When looking at the [Origen V93k docs](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/), I see that Origen will convert a Ruby styled variable to the camel case required by the V93k, but would it handle a variable with  an actual period in it?  I am storing them using the Origen::Parameters::Set class like so, but to retrieve the correct parameter name, I would have to write some 'parameter name flattener' method.

```
params.bist.Softset.PatternInfo0.EdgesPerVector = "2"
params.bist.Softset.PatternInfo0.FuseProgramming = "false"
```

Before I write said method, does Origen already have a way to handle this case already that is not part of the docs?  If not, would a PR be well received?

thx

Answer (score 0):

It would handle a period in the C++ parameter name, [the example here](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/#Custom_Test_Methods) contains a parameter called 'An.UnusualName'.

When you supply the parameter name via a string like this then it is rendered verbatim into the test flow:

```
tm_1:
  "An.UnusualName" = "blah"
```

To assign a value to this in an interface though then you need to convert the period to an underscore, Origen will create both the fully lower-cased and underscored accessor and also one with only the periods converted to underscores:

```
t = test_methods.my_lib.my_test
t.an_unusual_name = "blah"
t.An_UnusualName                # => "blah"
```

It would add significant complication to generate filler objects on the fly to support `t.An.UnusualName = "blah"` and I don't think it is worth it - the existing API is fine for humans.

I can see that supporting the name with the period might be preferable for scripting though. 
An easier approach that would provide what is needed would be to add a set_param method or similar to [this class](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/lib/origen_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/test_method.rb):

```
t.set_param("An.UnusualName", "blah")
```

Comment: Ok thanks Ginty.  I will play around with my test method params a bit and see how it shakes out.  This dilemma did provide me cause to write my first recursive method in a while to unpack the Origen::Parameter:Set into the proper syntax for the test method.